# Browser.OpenAsync("url"); not working on Samsung Tab with api 30 os 11 in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I am using Xamarin Essential nuget for opening url in browser but Browser.OpenAsync("url") not working for Samsung Tab with api 30 and os 11 could anyone suggest solution for it?

Comment: I do not have Samsung Tab. But i tested on Android 11 of emulator. The code works. What does the not working mean? Did you get errors? Have you try the code below with optimized system browser?  `Browser.OpenAsync("https://www.google.com.hk/", BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred); ` Does it still not work?

Comment: I have tried Browser.OpenAsync("https://www.google.com.hk/", BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred); still not working means it will redirect to browser and white page opens and suddenly redirect to my app

Comment: I do not have the specific device to reproduce. You could post your issue to check if it is occurs on specific device. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Answer (score 1):

There is a [package visibility requirement](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9) that android has as of Android 11.

Adding the following queries to you Android Manifest should work:

```
<queries>
<intent>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<data android:scheme="http"/>
</intent>
<intent>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<data android:scheme="https"/>
</intent>
</queries>
```

Goodluck!

Comment: I have tried this already but not working

Comment: working for me on Android 12